# How to make iOS app show in Files app Locations?

Tags: ios, swift, file, files-app

My iOS app is something like a cloud service, which interacts with Files app, downloading files into it and uploads from it.

When I open Files app and tap Browse, then Edit, I can see a list of `Locations` where other cloud services like OneDrive, DropBox etc are in the list, but my app is not.

What could be the reason? Maybe these apps have a specific category in the App Store? I have also made sure that there are files downloaded into my app, and there is my app's folder in Files's `On my iPhone`

[image: 1]

Comment: Your app must tell iOS that it can handle files.  This is done by adding the appropriate item(s) to your app's `Info.plist`.  [I quickly found this older article](https://bignerdranch.com/blog/working-with-the-files-app-in-ios-11/) that seems to show what you need.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks @meaning-matters, I have check and I already have those two properties in my Info.plist:
UIFileSharingEnabled &
LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace

Comment: I mean those two properties enables you to have your app as Folder in `On my iPhone` but I already have it. I want it to be in a list of locations like the Dropbox on the posted image.

Comment: Hey @stackich, did you manage to figure out this one? I’m currently trying to achieve the same

Comment: Hi @SantiagoIgnacioPoli, unfortunately no. But it definitely has to do something with "File Provider Extension", you can find it by pressing "+" button under the list of targets. Good luck, write me if you find something.

Comment: Hi @SantiagoIgnacioPoli did you manage to solve this?